# Restrict special characters & space programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I want to restrict user from entering special characters & space programmatically.
Below is my code

```
InputFilter[] alphaNumericFilter = new InputFilter[2];
        alphaNumericFilter[0] = new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                for (int k = start; k < end; k++) {
                    boolean isLetterOrDigit = Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(k));
                    boolean isSpaceChar = Character.isSpaceChar(source.charAt(k));
                    if ((source.length() > 0 && isSpaceChar) ||
                            (!isLetterOrDigit && !isSpaceChar) ||
                            (isSpaceChar && TextUtils.isEmpty(dest))) {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
```

on pressing space it deleting last character.

Comment: can you please clarify what are the acceptable input for your edittext is it only ( a-z A-Z 0-9) or somewhat else

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally I have resolved this issue by adding below line in the code

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

This line will not show suggestions on keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
public static InputFilter getAlphaNumericInputFilter(){
        return new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                       Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                if(source.equals("")){ // for backspace
                    return source;
                }
                if(source.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")){
                    return source;
                }
                return "";
            }
        };
    }
```

Here If you can just changes matches string according to your requirement for eg. avoid space with alphanumeric then It should like this:[a-zA-Z0-9]+.

Hope It help you !

Comment: what about special chaaracters?

Comment: @MohsinSyd If you see the code matches string is those string which u want to support. Special character is already avoided bcoz no special character include in match string.

Comment: Its allowing me to enter space

Comment: @MohsinSyd use as it is my above code .It will allow space with alphanumeric string.

Comment: @MohsinSyd I read your question,If I am getting correctly then you want to restrict all special character and space for user input, so I edit my answer pls check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141937/discussion-between-vikas-tiwari-and-mohsinsyd).

Answer (score 1):

**Use this code to filter your edittext**

```
 private String yourCharacterThatYouWantToBlock= " ~#^|$%&*!";

        private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                if (source != null && yourCharacterThatYouWantToBlock.contains(("" + source))) {
                    return "";
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
```

> Now apply this filter to your edittext.

```
 yourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputFilter alphaNumericFilter = new InputFilter() {   
     @Override  
     public CharSequence filter(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, Spanned arg3, int arg4, int arg5)  
     {  
         for (int k = arg1; k < arg2; k++) {   
             if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(arg0.charAt(k))) {   
             return ""; 
             }  
         }
         return null;
     }  
 };   
 mFirstName.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ alphaNumericFilter});
```